# Update order status on click of place order with post data to controller

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

How can I post some additional parameters to the custom controller and update the order with order status?

With a custom payment module, the payment is processing on the checkout page with JS. I need to update the order status after place order.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create `etc/events.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeOrderStatus" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create `Vendor/Module/Observer/ChangeOrderStatus.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeOrderStatus implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setStatus('processing');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean`. And then check it.